# Extract from string in BigQuery using regexp_extract

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, standards

I have a long string in BigQuery where that I need to extract out some data.

Part of the string looks like this:

`...  source: "agent"  resolved_query: "hi"  score: 0.61254  parameters ...`

I want to extract out data such as `agent`, `hi`, and `0.61254`.

I'm trying to use regexp_extract but I can't get the regexp to work correctly:

```
select
regexp_extract([col],r'score: [0-9]*\.[0-9]+') as score,
regexp_extract([col],r'source: [^"]*') as source
from [table]
```

What should the regexp be to just get `agent` or `0.61254` without the field name and no quotation marks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
select
regexp_extract([col],r'score:\s*(\d*\.?\d+)') as score,
regexp_extract([col],r'resolved_query:\s*"([^"]*)"') as resolved_query,
regexp_extract([col],r'source:\s*"([^"]*)"') as source
from [table]
```

Here,

- `score:\s*(\d*\.?\d+)` matches `score:` string, then any zero or more whitespaces, and then there is a capturing group with ID=1 that captures zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `resolved_query:\s*"([^"]*)"` matches  a `resolved_query:` string, zero or more whitespaces, `"`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"` and then matches a `"` char
- `source:\s*"([^"]*)"` matches  a `source:` string, zero or more whitespaces, `"`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"` and then matches a `"` char.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. And I especially appreciate the explanation of what regex is doing - really helped me understand as it is not intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I love non-trivial approaches - below one of such -

```
select * except(col) from (
  select col, split(kv, ': ')[offset(0)] key,
    trim(split(kv, ': ')[offset(1)], '"') value,
  from your_table,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(col, r'\w+: "?[\w.]+"?')) kv
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('source', 'resolved_query', 'score'))
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '...  source: "agent"  resolved_query: "hi"  score: 0.61254  parameters ... ' col union all
  select '...  source: "agent2"  resolved_query: "hello"  score: 0.12345  parameters ... ' col 
)
```

the output is

[image]

As you might noticed, the benefit of such approach is obvious - if you have more fields/attributes to extract - you do not need to clone the lines of code for each of attribute - you just add yet another value in last line's list - the whole code is always the same